Tensofflow model returns random predictions
I am new to ML and tensorflow
I have a python script to load and train my model, which trains very fast, but being a newbie, I don't really know what it should do.
The source images are vertically oriented pennies (lincoln's head is upright) @ 400x400x3
my image dataset is built using only 10 master images that I augment manually to get rotated and shifted images in the dataset
10 images x 90 rotations == 900 images non-shifted
or
10 images x 90 rotations x 17 shifts == 15300 images shifted
I have not been able to find an example of building a custom image dataset like this. all of the examples seem to focus on using a pre-existing mnist dataset, or using image_dataset_from_directory, which expects all of the files to exist.
Because I an unsure if the problem is image related, I am only using the non-shifted images for testing.
The test images are what the training images were created from, before they were rotated to the correct orientation, so in my deductive reasoning, I should have a high probability of matching on something....
When I run predictions from test images, the results seem random.
I have tried various layers, image resolutions, all with similar results.
while training the accuracy seems very low to me.
again, I am new to ML and tensorflow, so I don't know what "normal" is...
Because the issue (or issues) can be in so many places, I don't really know where to start.
images:
def LoadImage(path):
    # load and normalize an image
    #print('loading image '+path)
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = img.astype(float) / 255.0
    return img

baseimg = LoadImage(TrainingImagesDir+f)
for angle in range(0,360,4):
    rotated = RotateImage(baseimg, angle)
    label = 0 + int(angle/4)
    train_images.append(rotated)
    train_labels.append(label)

dataset:
train_images_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_images, name='train images')
train_labels_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_labels, name='train labels')

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((train_images_tensor, train_labels_tensor))

model:
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(arrClasses))
    ])
    loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)

    model.compile(
        optimizer=opt,
        loss=loss_fn,
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )

training:
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=LogDir)

model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=valid_ds,
    verbose=1,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
)

I have tried to change the layers by referencing different sample code online, but I do not understand how to pick the different layers to identify "features". I haven't found a good resource to guide me.
Before I go down the rabbit hole of fixing the model definition, I would like to confirm that is the issue.
Epoch 1/10 1/1 [==============================] - 1s 938ms/step - loss: 4.7652 - accuracy: 0.0116 - val_loss: 4.6423 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 Epoch 2/10 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 313ms/step - loss: 4.7536 - accuracy: 0.0112 - val_loss: 4.6310 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 Epoch 3/10 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 266ms/step - loss: 4.7422 - accuracy: 0.0109 - val_loss: 4.6199 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 Epoch 4/10 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 266ms/step - loss: 4.7329 - accuracy: 0.0119 - val_loss: 4.6088 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 Epoch 5/10 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 328ms/step - loss: 4.7249 - accuracy: 0.0125 - val_loss: 4.5982 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 Epoch 6/10 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 423ms/step - loss: 4.7147 - accuracy: 0.0128 - val_loss: 4.5878 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 Epoch 7/10 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 312ms/step - loss: 4.7023 - accuracy: 0.0122 - val_loss: 4.5784 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 Epoch 8/10 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 312ms/step - loss: 4.6969 - accuracy: 0.0112 - val_loss: 4.5697 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 Epoch 9/10 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 360ms/step - loss: 4.6897 - accuracy: 0.0121 - val_loss: 4.5618 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 Epoch 10/10 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 390ms/step - loss: 4.6806 - accuracy: 0.0120 - val_loss: 4.5546 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Where do you define your validation set?

You only train with one batch? I don't think Stack Overflow is the right place for your question, since the problem is not really the code you are writing, but just lack of general Machine Learning theory.

Totally agree to statemachine’s comment in here. My suggestion is that use a standard dataset and an end-to-end working code to start to play around. Read: mnist data using tensor flow from the official documentation examples. Most of your issues are fundamental and fixing these will save you a lot of time down the line.
